# How to check if tow columns are duplicate when INSERT data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

There is a way that MySQL to check record which is going to INSERT is duplicate or not is using:

```
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

But as the document says: `the KEY` to check is the `primary key`.And in my situation,I need to check `tow fields (columns)` to make sure it is duplicate or not.My table structure:

```
auto_id  user_id  file_id file_status
1        1        12        1
2        3        12        0
3        1        17        1
4        4        31        1
5        1        41        0
6        4        31        0
7        1        18        1
8        5        11        0
9        1        10        0
```

E.g:Maybe like:

```
ON DUPLICATE user_id,file_id UPDATE file_status = 0;
```

if `user_id and file_id which in one record were duplicate`,I will `update` the `file_status to 0`.

Thank you very much!!

**[update]**

So,I have to do it in several steps!?

First, find out the records exist or not:

```
SELECT auto_id FROM MyTable WHERE user_id='user_id' AND file_id='file_id'.
```

Second, decide to INSERT new record or UPDATE according to the SELECT result!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also create a stored procedure and check if the file_id already exists or not:

```
drop if procedure exists check_user_files;
create procedure check_user_files
(
    in p_file_id smallint
)
begin
    declare v_success tinyint unsigned default 0;

    if not exists (select 1 from user_files where file_id = p_file_id) then

        [....] -- insert statement

    else

        [....] -- remove or update

    end if;

    select v_success as success;
end;
```

And where are u using `auto_id` for? I think its unnecessary here?

Comment: How can I call the store procedure at multi-times to check all records!

Comment: you can do it by `call check_user_files(file_id)` its just like a php function but then only with call before it

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the duplicate check is for the violation of any unique index as well as the primary key. At least according to the [manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion, if you have you're main id (auto_id) on auto increment then why not make those 2 columns your primary key so if you try to enter a value that matches it will through an error

Comment: With your suggestion,because the auto_id is different,so MySQL will not through an error.